# Understanding interface injection

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, interfaces

Quoting the definition of interface injection  from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Interface_injection) :

> The advantage of interface injection is that dependencies can be completely ignorant of their clients yet can still receive a reference to a new client and, using it, send a reference-to-self back to the client. In this way, the dependencies become injectors

I wish to understand each part of what is said there.

Let me put the example here from the mentioned source:

```
// Service setter interface.
public interface ServiceSetter {
    public void setService(Service service);
}

// Client class
public class Client implements ServiceSetter {
    // Internal reference to the service used by this client.
    private Service service;

    // Set the service that this client is to use.
    @Override
    public void setService(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

Now let me split the quotation in parts and try to explain them :

part1 : "..dependencies can be completely ignorant of their clients.." - quite understandable

part2: "..dependencies can be completely ignorant of their clients **yet can still receive a reference to a new client** and, using .. " - bold part is obscure. **Q1)** Client gets a reference to the dependency not the vice versa, right ?

part3: "..can still receive a reference to a new client and, using it, send a reference-to-self back to the client..." - quite understandable

part4: ".. In this way, **the dependencies become injectors**.."- bold part is obscure. **Q2)** Dependencies are being injected. So how can they themselves be injectors ?

**Q3)** Dependency is obviously injected in the example. Can we say that interface is also being injected only to enable the injection of the dependency in the example ?

Comment: To the downvoters: if you don't like the question, you had time enough to tell the OP about your concerns in [this former meta post](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8854/will-it-be-a-good-fit-for-this-site-to-ask-for-explanation-of-interface-injectio). So if you still want to downvote now, please leave a comment (or stay away).

Answer (score 3):

> part2: "..dependencies can be completely ignorant of their clients **yet can still receive a reference to a new client** and, using .. " - bold part is obscure. Q1) Client gets a reference to the dependency not the vice versa, right?

Think of the term "dependency" here not just of the `Service` class itself, but of a library or framework where this class is located. Further assume for a moment that the `Service` object cannot be constructed at construction time of the `Client` object for some reason. The "interface injection" then makes it possible for the library to provide a function (maybe in some kind of factory or builder class) which gets the formerly constructed client object (as a `ServiceSetter` implementation), constructs the Service object and injects the `Service` object at the point in time when it is possible.

In pseudo code:

```
// assume this class is located in the same framework
// where "Service" lives
public class ServiceInjector
{
     public void Inject(ServiceSetter client)
     {
           // ...
           // maybe some reusable framework logic
           // to derive construction parameters 
           // for new service here
           // ..
           Service service = new Service(/*...*/);
           client.setService(service);
     }
}
```

So the "Dependency" - the library where `ServiceInjector` and `Service` are located - does not have know the concrete client object, still `ServiceInjector` can inject a `Service` object into the client.

(Assume the client object has to be constructed earlier, maybe it is needed first for making it possible to decide if `Inject` is ever called. Then "constructor injection" would not be possible here.)

> part4: ".. In this way, **the dependencies become injectors**.."- bold part is obscure.

This fits perfectly to what I wrote above: if you think the term "dependency" here refers to the full framework/library, the function I described is such an "injector".

And yes, I agree, the usage of the term "dependency" with slightly different meanings in mind does not make the Wikipedia article very readable.

Comment: can you provide at least some level of  pseudo code to understand the answer ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed: you are welcome

Comment: can you give the example in code to explain what you said ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed: can you please give us a hint first where you precisely have problems to follow what I already wrote?

Comment: From Wikipedia -the dependency's interface provides an injector method that will inject the dependency into any client passed to it.- This might help to clarify Doc's understanding of "dependency" here. If "dependency" was a single class, it could not provide us with an interface and an injector at the same time without breaking a handful of good design principles. It led me to think in dependency as "a whole" or, being more accurate, as a component or library. Indeed, Wikipedia's use for "dependency" is somewhat vague or imprecise.